# Error with Titanium when I distribute Android App

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-modules

after the upgrade to the new Titanium Studio and it's CLI I get this errors every time I try to Distribute my Android App:

> For help, run: titanium help build
>
> [ERROR] :  Missing required option: --alias
>
> [ERROR] :  Missing required option: --key-password

The problem is that I have setted Password and Alias in the configuration.
Why this happen? 
I tried everything: Changing Configuration, Creating New One etc etc

Someone knows a way to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem today, but I found the solution for my case.

There must be a bug in the Studio that makes you cannot CHANGE the alias in the alias field on the Run Configurations (well, you can change it, but it recovers the first name you wrote the first time)

In my case I wrote a BAD alias. To fix it, I deleted the Configuration and create a new one, with the right alias name. Then it worked.

Tell me if you are able to do it.